# Can I create an entity by default with core data?

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I'm creating a project in Xcode 7.3.1 that uses core data to store a "UserProfile" entity with three attributes. I have set up default values for these attributes but is there any way that I can set it so that a UserProfile entity is created the first time the app is run by default? I will only ever need one of these entities but I will need to access and modify the attributes as the app is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things about this:

1. No, there is no way to have an instance of a Core Data entity created by default. Your code must create it.
2. If you will only ever have one instance, Core Data is a completely inappropriate tool. It makes no sense at all. Store the data in user defaults, or if you prefer, in a separate property list file.